# How to make transition in React to display new HTML content based on updated state?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm very new on React, and I recently work on project called **Random Quote Machine**. So the goal is when user click Button, it triggered method inside React to change new value for state, and based on that it will re-render and display new quote on page. Which I successfully done it.

But there's no transition when the HTML content change. I want it to have like **fade-out fade-in transition** before it show the new quote.

This is my react component:

```
// START OF App Parent Component //
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      quote: "",
      author: "",
      color: ""
    }
    
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  /* RANDOMLY GET VALUE FROM QUOTE OBJECT and color arrays to store as state value */
  getData() {
    const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    const q = QUOTE[n]['quote'];
    const a = QUOTE[n]['author'];
    const c = colors[n];
    
    this.setState({
      quote: q,
      author: a,
      color: c
    });  
  }
  
  /* TRIGGER WHEN USER CLICK NEW QUOTE BUTTON, GET NEW VALUE FOR STATE TO RENDERED */
  handleClick() {
    this.getData();
  }
 
  /* THIS WILL HANDLE STATE TO PASS TO CHILD IN VERY FIRST RENDER */
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <QuoteBox quote={this.state.quote} author={this.state.author} color={this.state.color} handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
// END OF PARENT COMPONENT //

// START OF QUOTE BOX CHILD COMPONENT //
class QuoteBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  render() {
    {/* GET QUOTE-LEFT ICON FROM CODEPEN ASSETS*/}
    const iconQuote = <svg class="quote-icon" viewBox="0 0 512 512" title="quote-left">
  <path d="M464 256h-80v-64c0-35.3 28.7-64 64-64h8c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-8c-88.4 0-160 71.6-160 160v240c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h128c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V304c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-288 0H96v-64c0-35.3 28.7-64 64-64h8c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-8C71.6 32 0 103.6 0 192v240c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h128c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V304c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48z" />
</svg>
    
    {/* CHANGE THE BACKGROUND OF HTML BODY AFTER RENDER*/}
    document.body.style.background = this.props.color;
    
    return (
      <div>
        {/* START OF QUOTE BOX WRAPPER */}
          <div id="quote-box" className="quote-box">
            {/* QUOTE TEXT, ALWAYS UPDATE FROM PROPS PASSED BY PARENT'S STATE */}
            <div className="quote">
              <span style={{'color': this.props.color, 'fill': this.props.color}} id="text" class="quote-text">{iconQuote} {this.props.quote}</span>
            </div>
            
            {/* AUTHOR TEXT, ALWAYS UPDATE FROM PROPS PASSED BY PARENT'S STATE */}
            <div style={{'color': this.props.color}} id="author" className="quote-author">
              <span>- {this.props.author}</span>
            </div>
            
            {/* BUTTON WRAPPER */}
            <div className="buttons">
              
              {/* TWITTER BUTTON, UPDATE BACKGROUND FROM PROPS */}
              <a style={{'backgroundColor': this.props.color}} id="tweet-quote" class="tweet-quote-button" href="twitter.com/intent/tweet" target="_blank">
                tweet <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'twitter']} />
              </a>
              
              {/* NEW QUOTE BUTTON, UPDATE BACKGROUND FROM PROPS */}
              <button style={{'backgroundColor': this.props.color}} id="new-quote" class="new-quote-button" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>new quote</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        {/* END OF QUOTE BOX WRAPPER */}
        
        {/* START OF FOOTER */}
        <div className="footer">
          <span>created by <a href="https://codepen.io/thekevinkun" target="_blank">Kevinkun</a></span>
        </div>
        {/* END OF FOOTER */}
      
      </div>
    )
  }
}
// END OF CHILD COMPONENT //

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Or for better understanding you can look on my codepen: [Random Quote Machine Projects](https://codepen.io/thekevinkun/pen/poWpOyW)

As you can see, when you click **new quote** button, it will change the background color of body and button and color of text. But there's no transition.

I want to have transition like this: [freeCodeCamp Random Quote Machine](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/qRZeGZ)

So it would be very helpful if you write me simple animation code to make it look good. Because I'm stuck. Thank You.

Comment: You could store a boolean variable in your .jsx that determines whether you are loading a new quote. When you are loading a new quote, show the animation. Not sure what that animation would look like exactly but I hope that gets you started

Comment: @RhettHarrison I don't get it. How to make the transitions itself?

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways to animate mounting of components is use css keyframes. For example:

```
@keyframes animateMounting {
 0% {
    opacity: 0;
 }

 100% {
    opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

Then add to you component (in your case to quote\text):

```
.quote {
   animation: animateMounting .4s;
}
```

Now when your component render it'll 'fade in'. Of course you can change opacity to some transform effects or anything. Other option for your case is React Transition Group. https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/
With this library you can animate mounting and unmounting of react components.